# Mapping control keys in GVim without <c-> and i_ctrl_v

Tags: vim, xserver

I've got a problem that I've already solved on the X-server level (BTW: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04) but not in GVim.

I have a German keyboard layout with the letters <kbd>ö</kbd> and <kbd>ä</kbd> where <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> are on a qwerty keyboard. But now I want to change vim's normal mode mappings so I can type <kbd>ö</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd> as if it were <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, respectively. So I created an xmodmap file and mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. Now the xserver exhibits the right response (e.g. when I map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> I can erase the current line in `xterm`).

But somehow this doesn't work in gVim, and as far as I understand the gVim help it handles escape sequences like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+something in a special way (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd> in insert mode yields a plain <kbd>ö</kbd> in contrast to the behavior in `xterm`). But I don't understand how to solve this. Can anyone help me?

#### EDIT:

I've noticed that it *does* work when I run Vim in my terminal emulator (which is `guake`), but not in GVim (which I want to get working).

Comment: Yes, GVim doesn't make the difference between `<C-ö>` and `ö` (same with `é` and others on my french keyboard). Do you want something weird? MacVim doesn't care where `]` is physically located: `<C-$>` is the same as `<C-]>`.

Comment: Does "without <c-> and i_ctrl_v" in your title mean you don't want solutions that use Vim's `:map` command? (You don't want vim to know that you've done anything.)

Comment: What happens when you do `<C-v><C-ö>` and `<C-v><C-[>` in Gvim? Does it output the same character code? How does this result compare to when you do the same thing in Vim?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly try to use the `langmap` option like this:

```
:set langmap=ö[,ä]
```